# Adding Image to a pdf using cezpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi this is controller where in i am trying to add an image to my pdf using cezpdf . Can anyone please help me out as the image is not getting displayed in the pdf that is generated.

```
$this->load->library('cezpdf');
$this->cezpdf->ezStartPageNumbers(300,14,10,'','',1);
$this->cezpdf->selectFont('Times-Roman');

$this->cezpdf->ezImage(site_url("./includes/sitaralogo.jpg"));
```

Comment: ad what is error or output as well add view as well

Comment: check the image URL `$this->cezpdf->ezImage(site_url("./includes/sitaralogo.jpg"));`

Comment: there is no error . The other elements are getting displayed only my image is not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is malformed.

Assuming the base url is http://example.com the `site_url()` function will return http://example.com/./includes/sitaralogo.jpg. From the limited code I would assume using `site_url("/includes/sitaralogo.jpg")` would work.

Comment: Well i tried using the above answer but still got no output . Is there any other way where i can display my logo in my pdf using cezpdf libraries ?